# mysql inserting zero while using TIMESTAMPADD function

Tags: mysql, sql

> INSERT INTO `tbl_date_test` (`user_id`, `created`) VALUES ('1', 'TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,330,UTC_TIMESTAMP())');

above query does not inserting the current date and time, instead inserting the zero,

below one inserting while i execute above query,

> Delete    1   0000-00-00 00:00:00

Answer (score 2):

remove the quote, try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_date_test (user_id, created)
VALUES ('1', TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,330,UTC_TIMESTAMP()));
```